# Get half of float in python

Tags: python, list, slice

I have a list of large integers, of `10 digits(list = [1010101010, 1111000110,1111000111,1111000101]...)`. I want to group them 2 by 2 and to cut each one in half. For example, I have to group `list[0]` with list[1] and then split each one in half. the first half of `list[0]+last` half of `list[1]` will be the number I want to save and to use later. How do I slice the integers in half and get only their half to work with?
I managed to group the elements by 2, but I don't know how to split them and merge them.

```
 n = 2
 out = [list[k:k+n] for k in range(0,len(list),n)]
```

Comment: Is better if you add the expected output for the example

Comment: I don't understand the title. This question doesn't seem to be about floats at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could transform the int into string and then slice:

```
lst = [1010101010, 1111000110, 1111000111, 1111000101]
out = [lst[k:k+2] for k in range(0,len(lst), 2)]

result = [int(str(first)[:5] + str(second)[5:]) for first, second in out]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[1010100110, 1111000101]
```

**UPDATE**

If the input are numpy arrays, this should do it:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

lst = np.random.randint(2, size=(50, 10))
out = [lst[k:k+2] for k in range(0,len(lst), 2)]
result = [int(''.join(map(str,  first[:5].tolist() + second[5:].tolist()))) for first, second in out]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[100001110, 1011101000, 11111000, 11101, 101011110, 111110110, 1010000000, 1011110101, 11110000, 10011100, 100101010, 11111101, 1010000110, 100010101, 1110111001, 1110001, 1011110011, 101001100, 1001011010, 1110011110, 1100100111, 1110111100, 101101100, 1010110101, 1101000101]
```

Note that this solution removes leading zeros, by transforming the values into int.

Comment: Thank you! And if the list is generated like this: lst = np.random.randint(2, size=(50, 10)) ?

Comment: @luli Updated the answer!

Comment: @luli Glad I could aid! If my answer helped to solve your problem, please consider [marking it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/195035). That's the customary way of indicating that your question is "resolved" and thanking the person who helped you.